# How can generate visio file from existing C# code

Tags: c#, visio, bpmn

I built a complete project that work correctly, but i asked to generate Business model for the project that follow the code structure. My problem that the code is very large and can't draw the BPM manually. there is any way to extract the Visio 13 Bpmn from the code ? or any way to make this problem easiest.

Comment: But if the software is very large, it will most likely contain lots of classes and an automatically generated BPM will most likely be very confusing as well. Don't you think it would be better to manually create a BPM which only abstracts important parts of the software?

Comment: @Jakob , you are right the program contained a lots of classes and libs but, the requested to make bpmn everything in code that serve  help in code documentation such as gateways , tasks, process... etc. that is very difficult manually

Comment: I would recommend you forget about that. Visual representation was proved to be rather useless for code (if we are not talking about whiteboard). RIP Rational Rose - what a fuss there was like 10 years ago.. Where is it now? BPMN is not designed to document code, it's for modeling business processes. If your customer wants block schemes, tell him to invent a time machine and go back to 60-s, when computers were big and programs were small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do that, based on @Nikolay replay:
"Visual representation was proved to be rather useless for code (if we are not talking about whiteboard). RIP Rational Rose - what a fuss there was like 10 years ago.. Where is it now? BPMN is not designed to document code, it's for modeling business processes."
Thanks for help.